# Regexes (.NET dialect): strange behaviour of a capturing group

Tags: .net, regex

I'm stuck. Why does the group `path` in this code have value **2/3/4**, not **1/2/3/4**?
Where did **1/** go? What part of the expression matches **1/**?

```
var re = new Regex(@"^-/?(?'folder'((?'path'.+?)/)??[^/]*)/?$");
var m = re.Match("-1/2/3/4/5");
m.Groups["folder"].Value.Dump("Folder");
m.Groups["path"].Value.Dump("Path");
```

Comment: This dumps "1/2/3/4/5" then "1/2/3/4" for me...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, it's giving me `"2/3/4"` for the Path, too

Comment: Here is a screenshot of LINQPad: http://screencast.com/t/dfnJyMLQi9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is a behavioural difference between .NET 3.5 and 4.0. Here's a complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var re = new Regex(@"^-/?(?'folder'((?'path'.+?)/)??[^/]*)/?$");
        var m = re.Match("-1/2/3/4/5");
        Console.WriteLine("Folder: " + m.Groups["folder"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Path: " + m.Groups["path"].Value);
    }
}
```

Compiled and run under .NET 3.5:

```
Folder: 1/2/3/4/5
Path: 2/3/4
```

Compiled and run under .NET 4:

```
Folder: 1/2/3/4/5
Path: 1/2/3/4
```

I don't know why the behaviour should vary though...

EDIT: I've investigated this a bit further... under .NET 3.5, the group consists of two captures: "1" and "2/3/4". Under .NET 4 it's the single capture "1/2/3/4".

Comment: You *don't know*?? * incredulous * :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two captures for the Path group, `"1"` and `"2/3/4"` (which I don't quite understand, since you're <del>saying zero or one</del> not providing a quantifier for that group [and saying zero or one for the numbered capture group around that])

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing about your pattern is the use of `??` after the path group. Why aren't you using `?` only? This metacharacter makes the preceding item optional and it is excluded in the match if possible.

```
@"^-/?(?'folder'((?'path'.+?)/)??[^/]*)/?$"
                                ^
                 remove this  __|
```

New pattern: `@"^-/?(?'folder'((?'path'.+?)/)?[^/]*)/?$"`

Compiled under .NET 3.5 this returns the desired result. Under .NET 4.0 either pattern works, which indicates a difference in behavior as [Jon pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783354/regexes-net-dialect-strange-behaviour-of-a-named-group/4783568#4783568).

Comment: Ahmad, without this character I get invalid results for strings like `"-/16/"`. In this case I want `folder` to be `"16"` and `path` to be the empty string.

Comment: @thorn understood... in that case the .NET 4.0 behavior seems to address this issue.

Comment: BTW, my final version: `^-/?(?'folder'((?'path'.+)/(?!$))?[^/]*)/?$`